# Variable Scope Behaviour

Tags: java, android, scope

I have an android application and in one area of the app, I have a String variable set to `""` (I have tried null as well). Immediately after, I am performing an if function. Within the if, I change the variable and then use it outside of the if function but it turns out to be "" or null.

Can anyone explain this please?

```
String device = "";
if(DataModel.isTablet(getBaseContext())){
    device = "Tablet";
}
else{
    device = "Phone";
}
DataModel.displayConfirmNewDevice("New Device", String.format(DataModel.CONFIRM_NEW_DEVICE, device), code, ExistingMemberActivity.this);
```

`device` is the object which I am referring to. Even though the code runs at least one of the two if else statements, the `device` object is still null afterwards.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you check the device String, after giving it a value?

Comment: I strongly suspect you're misdiagnosing this. With the code you've given, the value of `device` will *definitely* be a reference to either `"Tablet"` or `"Phone"` after the `if` statement.

Comment: My suspect is that you check the device String by using **if (device == "")** instead of **if (device.equals(""))**

Comment: It appears that the device object is actually not null or "". The debugger whilst break-pointed was showing a pop-up window of "device = null" because that's how it's instantiated giving me the impression that it's null. My bad! Silly Pop-up window :(